# Problem with pkg installation on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, pkg

If I do `pkg update` I get:

```
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/meta.txz: Not Found
repository FreeBSD has no meta file, using default settings
pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/packagesite.txz: Not Found
Unable to update repository FreeBSD
```

Despite the fact that if I go to http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/ 
I can see meta.txz and packagesize.txz.

I did curl of http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/ and it shows

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

The output of  `fetch -o - -vv http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest inside the jail`

```
                                                                                                           /
scheme:   [http]
user:     []
password: []
host:     [pkg.FreeBSD.org]
port:     [0]
document: [/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/]
---> pkg.FreeBSD.org:80
looking up pkg.FreeBSD.org
connecting to pkg.FreeBSD.org:80
requesting http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/
>>> GET /freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/ HTTP/1.1
>>> Host: pkg.FreeBSD.org
>>> User-Agent: fetch libfetch/2.0
>>> Connection: close
>>>
<<< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
<<< Server: nginx
<<< Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2019 21:47:44 GMT
<<< Content-Type: text/html
<<< Content-Length: 162
<<< Connection: close
content length: [162]
<<<
offset 0, length -1, size -1, clength 162

404 Not Found

404 Not Found
nginx


fetch: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/: Not Found
```

Comment: Using the `curl` from Ubuntu Linux I don't get the error message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with FreeBSD and `fetch -vv`.

Comment: I have freebsd 9 , which version are you with?

Comment: The note there says it is no longer updated but, to me, that doesn't mean removed. However, I wonder if 32-bit support was removed from this very old version of FreeBSD. I doubt it so you might file a bug report to see if it's just a misconfiguration.

Comment: It isn't a removal, Rob, because (as I said) with `fetch -vv` on FreeBSD I, like the other commenter, get the actual repository.  There is no 404 page there when we fetch it.

Answer (score 3):

Open in browser http://pkg.freebsd.org/

You'll see the disclaimer "... NOT guarantee uptime ..." and the list of other mirrors

```
pkg0.bme.freebsd.org
pkg0.cyb.freebsd.org
pkg0.isc.freebsd.org
pkg0.kwc.freebsd.org
pkg0.twn.freebsd.org
pkg0.nyi.freebsd.org
```

You'll also see there is no such repo

> pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/

Instead there are FreeBSD 9 repos (no longer updated)

- http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:9:amd64/
- http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:9:i386/

Comment: So does this mean that with my current version of freebsd, I will no longer be able to install packages?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know who is managing freebsd:9:x86:32/. There is no such site in the list of mirrors.The End-of-Life FreeBSD 9 was January, 2017. Time to upgrade.

Comment: Both `fetch -o - -vv http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/` and `curl -v http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:32/latest/` get the correct page for me (and others!). You can still install packages for FreeBSD 9. Add results from verbose fetch or curl to your question (to see which mirror you resolve). Probably not an uptime issue as you get a 404.

Comment: I added it to the question. It shows 404 only inside the jail